# couldn't able to import pandas in django project in conda environment

Tags: django, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, miniconda

I am trying to do web app using django which uses pandas to read very large  csv file. I've follows these steps:

1. Installed miniconda and activated conda environment.
2. Installed pandas and django in this environment.
3. Created a new django project in this env **but this project folder was created out of miniconda folder**.

The problem is I am unable to import pandas in `views.py` of my django project.
It's throwing the exception `ImportError: no module named pandas`.

This django project created in conda env only right? Then why am I unable to import pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,Issue is resolved.

Its's working after i changed the python interpreter from default one  to interpreter which is there in conda environment where pandas are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you django project is using the conda environment you created? Why don't you open the python interpreter/interactive console and try if you can import pandas from there.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback faph.